# Efficient string parsing in C for Web Routing

Tags: c, rest

I'm writing a tiny hook for a super old web server that can't otherwise be upgraded (except manually like this). It is written in C and provides enough barebones stuff - set headers, mime types, etc. It does its own routing but can only return static files.

I have tested a simple web routing system that just uses `strstr` to see if a certain request was called; then I return some JSON data. What I would like to know is how to efficiently write a web routing process from scratch. My product is very specialized and only has one user on it at a time, and web access is often just for setup, so I'm not at all worried about 100s of requests per second. The max could be 5-10 requests per second for a tiny burst, then maybe 1 request per second while idle.

I think this gets in to things like tokenizing, or maybe just using regexps.. Things I will learn if necessary.

TLDR: How do I write this in the most efficient manner?

```
  /* requestPtr->path = "/user/123" */

   if(strstr(requestPtr->path, "/user/123") != NULL)
   {
       /* process the request */
   }
   else if(strstr(requestPtr->path, "/config/settings") != NULL)
   {
       /* process the request */
   }
   else if(/* and on and on */ )...
```

Comment: If `requestPtr->path` has only one of 2 values, then no need for the `if(strstr(requestPtr->path, "/config/settings")...`.   If `requestPtr->path` has other possiblities, best to post an idea of some those other values and their likely-hood of occurrences to "write this in the most efficient manner".

Comment: In this web router's case there would be 100s (maybe 300?) different requests. This will grow/shrink over time as well. There could be more slashes or less slashes. I would likely "group" things first, or use subrouters/sub processors. For example, anything starting with `/user` would go to a sub processor.

Comment: With _lots_ of strings to match against, consider hashing `requestPtr->path` and using a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

Answer (score 1):

strstr searches the whole length of your string for a match before failing.

If these matches are always from the root, or for all the ones where they are from the root, you could use strncmp, where you input n as the length of the test string, [or sizeof("/user/123/")-1 will be solved at compile time]. This will be significantly faster when the string is /not/ matched.

Note that I suggest you always include the trailing / in paths whenever it is appropriate, as it will stop you matching /user/123 against /user/1234

If you have some compares that are always looking for the end of a path, you can manufacture a pointer into the string for the right offset from the end and use strcmp. You could do one strlen of the pathstr before doing any compares, and remember to check the pathstr is long enough to do the subtraction in each case!

If you really need mid-position matches of complete path elements, then put in an outer loop which finds each / in your path string, then strncmp each of your test strings in turn inside the loop.

If you really don't have complete path elements, i.e. you want user/123 to match my_user/12345, but your test strings contain at least 1 slash, you could record the character offset of that slash, perhaps as the first byte of the test string (yuck)"\004user/123", and in the above loop, strncmp from back that many characters, if you are at least that many characters in.

Only where you have fragments of a single path element would you resort to strstr